# Graphql query constructing in python

Tags: python, graphql, shopify

```
payload = """ query GetOrders($num_els: Int, $created_at: String, $cursor: String) {
              orders(first: $num_els, query: $created_at, after: $cursor) {
                edges {
                  node{
                    email
                  }
                }
              }
            }"""
```

I try to send a simple query. The `$cursor` field can be empty.

```
variables = {'num_els': num_elements, 'created_at': f'created_at:>2022-01-10', 'cursor': None}
r = requests.post(constants['SHOPIFY_URL'], headers=headers,
                          json={'query': payload, 'variables': variables}).json()
```

However this gives me the

```
[{'message': 'Parse error on "query" (STRING) at [1, 2]', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column': 2}]}]
```

Even if I discard the a bit complicated part with `$created_at`, the problem continues. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

changing `Content-Type` to `application/json` worked as denoted [here](https://github.com/Shopify/graphql-js-client/issues/132)